# Terraform Combine Variable and String

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to do a rather simple task in Terraform and it's not working:

tfvars:

```
hosted_zone       = "example.com"
domain            = "my.${var.hosted_zone}"
```

route_53_record:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "regional" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id}"
  name    = "${var.domain}"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["4.4.4.4"]
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` I'm getting this:

```
+ aws_route53_record.regional
      id:                 <computed>
      allow_overwrite:    "true"
      fqdn:               <computed>
      name:               "my.${var.hosted_zone}"
      records.#:          "1"
      records.3178571330: "4.4.4.4"
      ttl:                "300"
      type:               "A"
      zone_id:            "REDACTED"
```

domain should be `my.example.com`. How do I join the variable hosted_zoned and a string to form domain?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can't use interpolation in a tfvars file.

Instead you could either join it directly in your Terraform like this:

#### terraform.tfvars

```
hosted_zone = "example.com"
domain      = "my"
```

#### main.tf

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "regional" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
  name    = "${var.domain}.${var.hosted_zone}"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["4.4.4.4"]
}
```

Or, if you always need to compose these things together you could use a local:

```
locals {
  domain = "${var.domain}.${var.hosted_zone}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "regional" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
  name    = local.domain
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["4.4.4.4"]
}
```

Comment: In terraform 0.13 interpolation is removed. How can we concat without interpolation?

Comment: It's not removed. You get a warning when using bare interpolation such as `name    = "${local.domain}"` instead of `name    = local.domain` but you can still use `"${var.domain}.${var.hosted_zone}"` to join two variables with another string (the `.`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping the dot?

```
      name:               "my\.${var.hosted_zone}"
```

Of course, you don't need the "domain" variable in .tvars then either.