# How to concat string to a variable in Terraform Template DSL

Tags: ansible, terraform, ansible-inventory, ansible-template, terraform-template-file

I am passing a `map` from terraform code to jinja2 for creating an ansible's `hosts` file. In the hosts file, I am printing the map using the following code and it is working fine.

```
1. %{ for key, value in cat ~}
2. [${ key }]
3. %{ for v in value ~} 
4. ${ v }
5. %{ endfor ~}

6. %{ endfor ~}
```

I am now trying to append `:children` with the key but it is not working. I tried the following 04 ways of changing the line 2 in the above code but no luck. Following the link [String concatenation in Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061439/string-concatenation-in-jinja)

```
Attempt 1:
[${ key|join(":children") }]

Attempt 2:
[${ key + ':children' }]

Attempt 3:
[${ key ~ ':children' }]

Attempt 4:
[${ key ~ ':children' ~}]
```

Comment: Not tested, but
-I don’t understand addressing variables using `$` in Jinja...
I know only addressing via ```{{ variable }}```...
-I would escape square brackets. Below I escape also complete `:children]` part: 
So maybe following will work:
```{{ '[' }} {{ key }} {{ ':children]' }}```

Comment: @KonstantinVolenbovskyi this is a Terraform template, so it is their own DSL.

Comment: `["${key}:children"]` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform Combine Variable and String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752049/terraform-combine-variable-and-string)

Comment: I tried that now `[${ key }:children]` and so far so good. I dont know if it will have a space or not i.e. `key :children` or will it be `key:children` the later is what I want. I will try `["${key}:children"]` that after above run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[${ key }:children]` that did the trick so the complete answer will be

```
%{ for key, value in cat ~}
[${ key }:children]
{ for v in value ~} 
${ v }
%{ endfor ~}

%{ endfor ~}
```

Which will give us

```
[blue:children]
[green:children]
```